# How to track changes to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to implement a class that can track changes made to a single DataFrame, save those changes, view the list of those changes and the past dataframe.
For example:

1. I have a dataframe ({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [9, 8, 7], "c": [10, 20, 30]})
2. Make some changes by adding resulting in dataframe ({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 3, 2], "c": [10, 20, 30], "sum":[15,25,35]}) and save it with a commit name "first".
3. I make further changes to this dataset and save it with a commit name "second".
4. Now, I need to be able to print the original dataset from step 1 and the dataset with the commit name "second"

Answer (score 0):

As a very basic proof of concept you could store different versions of a `DataFrame` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

versions = {}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [9, 8, 7],
    "c": [10, 20, 30]
})
versions['initial'] = df.copy()

df['sum'] = [15, 25, 35]
versions['first'] = df.copy()

df['further_changes'] = range(3)
df.drop(columns='a', inplace=True)
versions['second'] = df.copy()

print(versions['initial'])
print(versions['second'])
```

output:

```py
   a  b   c
0  1  9  10
1  2  8  20
2  3  7  30
   b   c  sum  further_changes
0  9  10   15                0
1  8  20   25                1
2  7  30   35                2
```